# Criei meu projeto, venho editando todos os dias, e recentemente do nada ele deixou de reconhecer um namespace existente

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net, namespace

Criei meu projeto no Visual Studio 2013, venho editando todos os dias, e recentemente do nada ele deixou de reconhecer um namespace existente.

O namespace aparece em vermelho com a mensagem "The type or namespace 'Models' does not exist in namespace 'Projeto.Models'

Porém ao executar meu projeto tudo roda normalmente, mesmo aparecendo este erro na Error List.
Parece ser um bug do Visual Studio, em outro computador abri o projeto e rodou normalmente !

Comment: Se em outro computador abre normalmente, não é problema no projeto, e sim algo específico em seu ambiente. Já tentou reparar ou até mesmo reinstalar o Visual Studio?

Answer (score 0):

clique com o botão direito no projeto em properties e verifique se o Default namespace está correto,  cheque  as referencias a este projeto também, remova e referencie novamente.

Comment: Ele encontra-se correto, acabei testando em outra máquina e deu certo, daí eu fiz a reinstalação do meu Visual Studio inteiro e voltou à funcionar. Mistérios da Ms....